# Firestore pagination - Is there any query compatible with firebase's limitToLast?

Tags: sorting, firebase, pagination, google-cloud-firestore

Is there a way to implement back pagination with firestore?
I am struggling to implement pagination with firestore, and there are limited firestore queries for it. Forward pagination can be made by **startAt** and **limit** method, that is ok. But back pagination can't be easily done, because we only have **endBefore**, and **endAt** method, and how can we get last *n* elements from given document? I know realtime database have method **limitToLast**. Is there any query like this for firestore? (Also I need to implement multiple sorting, so getting last documents with "ASC" or "DESC" sorting will not work)
Help much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The equivalent to the `limitToLast(...)` operation from the Firebase Realtime Database in Cloud Firestore is to order the data descending (which is possible in Firestore) and then just `limit(...)`. If you're having problems implement this, update your question to show what you've done.

I agree that this is a sub-optimal API for back-pagination, since you're receiving the items in reverse order.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem is I need to implement sorting as well as pagination like afs.collection('data', ref => ref.orderBy('field1', 'asc').orderBy(''field2', 'desc'). ...). Is there any way to keep these sorting result in pagination?
I reversed this query order (field1 => 'desc', field2 => 'asc', ...) , but not working.
thanks.

Comment: Finally I decided to move with Algolia and now it works great.

Answer (score 3):

Simpler answer: Firestore now has .limitToLast(), which works exactly as you think it does.  Used in my own (guess I need to publish it soon) Firestore Wrapper:

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// *** Paginate API ***

export const PAGINATE_INIT = 0;
export const PAGINATE_PENDING = -1;
export const PAGINATE_UPDATED = 1;
export const PAGINATE_DEFAULT = 10;
export const PAGINATE_CHOICES = [10, 25, 50, 100, 250, 500];

/**
 * @classdesc
 * An object to allow for paginating a table read from Firestore. REQUIRES a sorting choice
 * @property {Query} Query that forms basis for the table read
 * @property {number} limit page size
 * @property {QuerySnapshot} snapshot last successful snapshot/page fetched
 * @property {enum} status status of pagination object
 * @method PageForward pages the fetch forward
 * @method PageBack pages the fetch backward
 */

export class PaginateFetch {
  Query = null;
  limit = PAGINATE_DEFAULT;
  snapshot = null;
  status = null; // -1 pending; 0 uninitialize; 1 updated;
  /**
   * ----------------------------------------------------------------------
   * @constructs PaginateFetch constructs an object to paginate through large
   * Firestore Tables
   * @param {string} table a properly formatted string representing the requested collection
   * - always an ODD number of elements
   * @param {array} filterArray an (optional) 3xn array of filter(i.e. "where") conditions
   * @param {array} sortArray a 2xn array of sort (i.e. "orderBy") conditions
   * @param {ref} ref (optional) allows "table" parameter to reference a sub-collection
   * of an existing document reference (I use a LOT of structered collections)
   *
   * The array is assumed to be sorted in the correct order -
   * i.e. filterArray[0] is added first; filterArray[length-1] last
   * returns data as an array of objects (not dissimilar to Redux State objects)
   * with both the documentID and documentReference added as fields.
   * @param {number} limit (optional)
   * @returns {PaginateFetchObject}
   **********************************************************************/

  constructor(
    table,
    filterArray = null,
    sortArray = null,
    ref = null,
    limit = PAGINATE_DEFAULT
  ) {
    const db = ref ? ref : fdb;

    this.limit = limit;
    this.Query = sortQuery(
      filterQuery(db.collection(table), filterArray),
      sortArray
    );
    this.status = PAGINATE_INIT;
  }

  /**
   * @method Page
   * @returns Promise of a QuerySnapshot
   */
  PageForward = () => {
    const runQuery = this.snapshot
      ? this.Query.startAfter(_.last(this.snapshot.docs))
      : this.Query;

    this.status = PAGINATE_PENDING;

    return runQuery
      .limit(this.limit)
      .get()
      .then((QuerySnapshot) => {
        this.status = PAGINATE_UPDATED;
        //*IF* documents (i.e. haven't gone beyond start)
        if (!QuerySnapshot.empty) {
          //then update document set, and execute callback
          //return Promise.resolve(QuerySnapshot);
          this.snapshot = QuerySnapshot;
        }
        return this.snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
          return {
            ...doc.data(),
            Id: doc.id,
            ref: doc.ref
          };
        });
      });
  };

  PageBack = () => {
    const runQuery = this.snapshot
      ? this.Query.endBefore(this.snapshot.docs[0])
      : this.Query;

    this.status = PAGINATE_PENDING;

    return runQuery
      .limitToLast(this.limit)
      .get()
      .then((QuerySnapshot) => {
        this.status = PAGINATE_UPDATED;
        //*IF* documents (i.e. haven't gone back ebfore start)
        if (!QuerySnapshot.empty) {
          //then update document set, and execute callback
          this.snapshot = QuerySnapshot;
        }
        return this.snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
          return {
            ...doc.data(),
            Id: doc.id,
            ref: doc.ref
          };
        });
      });
  };
}

/**
 * ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 * @function filterQuery
 * builds and returns a query built from an array of filter (i.e. "where")
 * consitions
 * @param {Query} query collectionReference or Query to build filter upong
 * @param {array} filterArray an (optional) 3xn array of filter(i.e. "where") conditions
 * @returns Firestor Query object
 */
export const filterQuery = (query, filterArray = null) => {
  return filterArray
    ? filterArray.reduce((accQuery, filter) => {
        return accQuery.where(filter.fieldRef, filter.opStr, filter.value);
      }, query)
    : query;
};

/**
 * ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 * @function sortQuery
 * builds and returns a query built from an array of filter (i.e. "where")
 * consitions
 * @param {Query} query collectionReference or Query to build filter upong
 * @param {array} sortArray an (optional) 2xn array of sort (i.e. "orderBy") conditions
 * @returns Firestor Query object
 */
export const sortQuery = (query, sortArray = null) => {
  return sortArray
    ? sortArray.reduce((accQuery, sortEntry) => {
        return accQuery.orderBy(sortEntry.fieldRef, sortEntry.dirStr || "asc");
        //note "||" - if dirStr is not present(i.e. falsy) default to "asc"
      }, query)
    : query;
};
```

I also have the equivalent for CollectionGroup queries, and listeners for each as well.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this same issue, and not understanding why using `limit` with `endAt` wasn't returning the results I desired.  I was attempting to implement a list in which you could paginate in both directions, first forward and then backward back to the start of the list.

To remedy the situation I decided to just cache the `startAfter` `DocumentSnapshot` for each page so that one can move both directions, in this way I never have to use `endAt`.  The only time this will become an issue is if the collection of documents shifts or changes while the user is on a page other than the first page, but by returning to the first page it will reset to the beginning of the collection.

Comment: Only problem with that is that if you startAfter 17 pages later, you have to cache 17 documents, for example...

Comment: have you got a better way of solving it? for my own use case, the requirement to cache one document for each page was a valid tradeoff

Comment: Read my comment below, or use the offset() in cloud functions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Building upon Frank's answer...

Have something like this in your query...

```js
    if (this.next) {
      // if next, orderBy field descending, start after last field
      q.orderBy('field', 'desc');
      q.startAfter(this.marker);
    } else if (this.prev) {
      // if prev, orderBy field ascending, start after first field
      q.orderBy('field', 'asc');
      q.startAfter(this.marker);
    } else {
      // otherwise just display first page results normally
      q.orderBy('field', 'desc');
    }
    q.limit(this.pageSize);
```

and then reverse it when you get the query...

```js
    this.testsCollection
            .valueChanges({ idField: 'id' })
            .pipe(
              tap(results => {
                if (this.prev) {
                  // if previous, need to reverse the results...
                  results.reverse();
                }
              })
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

I just want to share my code for Firestore pagination. 
I am using react hooks w/ NextJS.

You will need to have "useFirestoreQuery" hook, which can be found here. 
https://usehooks.com/useFirestoreQuery/

So here is my set up.

```
/* Context User */
const {user} = useUser()

/* States */
const [query, setQuery] = useState(null)
const [ref, setRef] = useState(null)
const [reverse, setReverse] = useState(false)
const [limit, setLimit] = useState(2)
const [lastID, setLastID] = useState(null)
const [firstID, setFirstID] = useState(null)
const [page, setPage] = useState(1)

/* Query Hook */
const fireCollection = useFirestoreQuery(query)

/* Set Ref, **When firebase initialized** */
useEffect(() => {
  user?.uid &&
    setRef(
      firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection('products')
        .where('type', '==', 'vaporizers')
    )
}, [user])

/* Initial Query, **When ref set** */
useEffect(() => {
  ref && setQuery(ref.orderBy('id', 'asc').limit(limit))
}, [ref])

/* Next Page */
const nextPage = useCallback(() => {
  setPage((p) => parseInt(p) + 1)
  setReverse(false)
  setQuery(ref.orderBy('id', 'asc').startAfter(lastID).limit(limit))
}, [lastID, limit])

/* Prev Page */
const prevPage = useCallback(() => {
  setPage((p) => parseInt(p) - 1)
  setReverse(true)
  setQuery(ref.orderBy('id', 'desc').startAfter(firstID).limit(limit))
}, [firstID, limit])

/* Product List */
const ProductList = ({fireCollection}) => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    let tempProducts = []
    let tempIDs = []
    const {data} = fireCollection
    for (const key in data) {
      const product = data[key]
      tempIDs.push(product.id)
      tempProducts.push(<ProductRow {...{product}} key={key} />)
    }
    if (reverse) {
      tempProducts.reverse()
      tempIDs.reverse()
    }
    setFirstID(tempIDs[0])
    setLastID(tempIDs.pop())
    setProducts(tempProducts)
  }, [fireCollection])

  return products
}
```

I moved the 'ProductList' outside of the component with a context provider, but this is the gist of it.

**Note.**
If you are looking for the total number of products. I suggest you keep up with the totals with these cloud functions. You will need to store your totals in a separate collection. I call mine 'shortcuts'.

```
exports.incrementProducts = functions.firestore
  .document('products/{id}')
  .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
    const createdProduct = snap.data()
    /* Increment a shortcut collection that holds the totals to your products */
  })

exports.decrementProducts = functions.firestore
  .document('products/{id}')
  .onDelete((snap, context) => {
    const deletedProduct = snap.data()
    /* Decrement a shortcut collection that holds the totals to your products */
  })
```

[image]

**Don't Forget**
Make sure you set your indexes for all this to work. Here is what mine looks like.
[image]