# A clarification on Google Firestore query pagination

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently struggling in understanding how to paginate a firestore collection.
Say I have a collection with 10 docs and I have stored *doc5* in my vue.js-based app.

If I wanted to fetch doc6 and doc7, I would issue the following pseudo-command:

```
query.startAt(doc5).limit(2).get().then(snapshot => ...)
```

What If I wanted to go two docs backwards relative to *doc5*? My first guess was to issue the following pseudo-command:

```
query.endBefore(doc5).limit(2).get().then(snapshot => ...)
```

Unfortunately, my guess is not correct. I actually obtain doc1 and doc2. 
This thing is driving me nuts. It is quite evident that I didn't understand the logic behind *endBefore()*. I did read the firebase docs but couldn't find any light.

May I ask for your merciful help?

If needed, I can provide more context... I am trying to isolate the issue and be as clear as possible.

Comment: You'll need to reverse the sort order of the query, and then `startAfter(doc5).limit(2)`. Also see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48342525/firestore-pagination-is-there-any-query-compatible-with-firebases-limittolast

Comment: Thank you Frank. I was pretty sure you would answer to this :-) I follow you on firebase casts. Can I ask you if google has any plan (near or not) of improving this specific issue?

Comment: The API works as intended, I've used it to page-up myself. While another API might be shorter, it is hard to argue that case objectively, especially with few examples. What really helps is if you show what you thought would work (like you've done), then write the code that actually works (by reversing the query), and [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) for the change.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firestore pagination - Is there any query compatible with firebase's limitToLast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48342525/firestore-pagination-is-there-any-query-compatible-with-firebases-limittolast)