# Firestore order by and limit

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I am writing a simple chat feature within my application. Given the fact some users will have multiple messages within a conversation, I need to provide reverse pagination so they can load previous messages when scrolling. From the model side, each message has a timestamp (a time interval) so that it's easy to query.

I'm able to query and order desc from the date field, however... the second I limit the response to X number of items.. somehow the date field is omitted and I get the first 5 in the collection, not the 5 I want ordered by date. How can I fix this?

**Example**

message one: 1

message two: 2

message three: 3

message four: 4

When I order desc, I get the right list [1,2,3,4,5]. When I limit(2), it gives me [1,2] but what I really want is [3, 4].

I am missing something obvious?

**Update:**

collection: "conversations". sub collection "messages".

Collection id is done by aggregating both user ids so it's easier to query a conversation of 2 users.

```
db.collection("conversations")
                .document(identifier)
                .collection("messages")
                .order(by: "sentDate", descending: false)
                .limit(to: 5)
                .addSnapshotListener({ snapshot, error in
                    guard let document = snapshot else { return }
                    let messages = document.documents.map {
                        return Message.fromJSON($0.data())
                    }

                    observable.onNext(messages as! [Message])
                    observable.onCompleted()
                })
```

Comment: Please include the actual code for your query/queries in your question. It would also help to see the collection/documents that you're querying.

Comment: I updated my original question, thanks @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: I guess what I want here is a limitToLast ? Type of thing

Comment: There is no equivalent for the realtime database's `limitToLast()`. Instead you'll have to reverse the sort-order, and then re-reverse the items in the client. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48342525/firestore-pagination-is-there-any-query-compatible-with-firebases-limittolast

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen but wouldn't this destroy pagination?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen can u assist? Having issues with pagination using this method. How can I deal with it?

Comment: "wouldn't this destroy pagination?" Not if you properly reverse the sort order and then the children.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen using after: or before: document snapshot API?

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting [1,2,3,4] during **.order(by: "sentDate", descending: false)**,

and [1,2] when using  **.order(by: "sentDate", descending: false).limit(to: 2)**,
then you can do the following:

1. Use **.order(by: "sentDate", descending: true)** to get [4,3,2,1]
2. Then use **.limit(to: 2)** to get [4,3]
3. At last use **.reverse()** before mapping it.

```
(ie. let messages = document.documents.reverse().map line in your code)
```

And you will get [3,4].